# Which city is shown in the film "A trip to Wiesbaden"?

Tags: identify-this

This is an image from the film "[A trip to Wiesbaden](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0136470/)" (USSR, 1989).

[image: City skyline]

In the film, this skyline is supposed to be the skyline of [Wiesbaden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiesbaden) (a city in Germany). Well, this is definitley not Wiesbaden (I've been residing there).

Where is it?

---

*Information which may be useful: the film was shot in cooperation with Czechoslovakia, so this might be a town on the territory of the modern Czech Republic or Slovakia.*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I am pretty sure that this is in Vienna and that the church is St. Stephen's Cathedral. I can't find a picture of the church from that angle, but you can find one from a slightly different angle [here](https://www.wien.info/en/sightseeing/sights/st-stephens-cathedral). You can recognize both the high, spiky tower and the smaller dome on the other side with the patina roof.

Comment: Yes, this is it! I watched a couple of videos on youtube and found one with this very angle - [on 2min4sec](https://youtu.be/BAG8cFfnMEE?t=2m2s).

Answer (score 15):

Supplementary answer: Instead of looking for Youtube videos, another way to double check the perspective is to use the 3D-capability of Google Maps!

Building with four lower and central higher tower directly left of the cathedral tower: town hall

Spiky white tower further left: St. Michael's Church

Green dome even further left: Hofburg - former imperial palace

[image]

Comment: Yes, I tried but the browser didn't want to load the 3D view of this very spot from this angle! It was possible to see the cathedral from another angle though. And Apple Maps doesn't have a 3d view of Vienna (what I find strange...)